# SUPEE-6788 - Patching file notice, but file not patched

Tags: patches, supee-6788

SUPEE-6788 - Patching file notice, but file not patched

We read:

`patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

and then when we check the files the patch is not applied

There is an htaccess error / patch cannot be applied - but we run nginx

How can I force the patch to apply?

Comment: If there's a single error line, the patch will not apply. On running, the patch tests all items and then gives you a report listing everything that will apply and everything that will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the .htaccess and .htaccess.sample with an original stock version, then run the patch. I had the same problem and it was because my .htaccess lines weren't matching up, so no files were patched.

Comment: Thanks - I manually applied some fixes, but these I also had to remove again to get the full patch file working. However now I see my blocks are not in order and whitelisted so we needed to run whitelist (https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox) ... trouble is that when I try and access the whitelist tables in settings I receive an error "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage.permission_variable' doesn't exist
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mage.permission_block' doesn't exist"

Answer (score 0):

please download the latest magento 1.9.2.2 and replace with current version.

Please take backup of current version before uploading new files.